# Is the proposition "There are 4 regular solids" true or false

Tags: propositional-calculus

I am currently learning about propositions and came across a statement in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0exBzsexUoI):

*There are 5 regular solids*: **true**

*There are 6 regular solids*: **false**

But then I am wondering if a statement *There are 4 regular solids* will be considered **true** or **false**.

e.g., I believe the following results:

*There are at-least 4 regular solids*: **true**

*There are exactly 4 regular solids*: **false**

To be more specific, there are definitely at-least 4 regular solids, but without *at-least* or *exactly* as qualifying adverbs, how should the above proposition be interpreted?

Comment: It's ambiguous, for precisely the reasons you stated. There is no right answer. If given such a statement, you should  either (a) ask the asker for clarification, or (b) include both answers, explaining the distinction between each and so on.

Comment: A square has three sides. True or false?

Comment: @Raffaele thanks for pointing out a simpler case. If your case were asked in a **geometry** class, the answer is clear (wrong). But in a logic class, I am not sure (and thats the reason for my question)

Comment: I would take your reading of the problem even further: are there $6$ regular solids? Well, $6$ cubes (of different edge lengths if you will) do the trick... The question, to be more precise, should state something like "Are there $6$ non-equivalent regular solids?".